# How to send a notification from a web application to a windows service in same network

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-services, signalr

I have a web application and lots of PCs that hosted in the same network. Each PC has windows service application that currently running on and it can connect to the server. Using web application, I am uploading some files to the server.

Once a file upload success, How can I send a notification to those windows services?

Is this possible with using SignelR for this task? If the answer is yes, What is the approach that I should follow.

Each application developed by using C# and web application hosted server is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Thats not the sens that you mark a answer as correct. After that you have totally another problem and you change the content of the question. Please change it back and add an additional new question. Your initial question was answered correct!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use signalr

*Server*

Your webapplication is the "signalR Server". Here you can read how to make the serverpart:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server
(Simple make a hub, where the clients can connect to)

*Clients*

Here you can read how you can make your client inside your service. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client
(The clients should initial connect to the server, and after that you can send messages from server to client)

Take also a look to:

- https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/04/SelfHosting-SignalR-in-a-Windows-Service
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SignalR-self-hosted-in-6ff7e6c3

Another possibility is WCF (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf)  but my opinion is that you will get faster a running result with signalr.